# How to stylize text with PHP using GD/Imagick?

Tags: php, text, imagick

I use `imagettftext()` function to add a caption to the image:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLlWN.png)
Background and captions are separate.

How could I apply the style similar to this one, is it possible with Imagick?
I need to create the 3D effect for the letters.
[required style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJocl.png)

I was trying to use and combine letters' images, but I think it's not a good solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use PHP exec(), you can call my Unix Bash Imagemagick script, texteffect2 at my web site http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html. It will do bevel and other effects. Here is the script command for doing a bevel:

```
texteffect2 -t "bevel" -e bevel -s plain -f Ubuntu-Bold -p 200 -c red -bg none result.png
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
-t is the text you want to use
-e is the effect you want
-s is whether to make it plain or add an outline
-f is the font name or font file
-p is the point size for the font
-c is the text color
-bg is the background color (none means transparent)
```

Here is the basic Imagemagick code to do the bevel effect:

```
convert -background none -font Ubuntu-Bold \
-pointsize 200 -fill "red" -gravity west label:"BEVEL" \
\( +clone -alpha Extract -write mpr:alpha -blur 0x8 -shade 135x30 \
-auto-level -function polynomial 3.5,-5.05,2.05,0.25 \
mpr:alpha -compose copy_opacity -composite \) \
-compose Hardlight -composite result.png
```

I do not know Imagick that well. So you might look here https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php for the Imagick equivalents or perhaps someone else who uses Imagick can convert it for you.

Answer (score 0):

the method is called [Imagick::embossImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.embossimage.php), where the text should be a separate layer, before merging the layers for output. just try to manually produce the desired effect with `GIMP2`, then you know the steps required to get there. the [gimp-imagemagick](https://github.com/sjgcit/gimp-imagemagick) plugin also appears useful for testing.